# Align button in Panel control

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I have written `UserControl` which contain two buttons in `Panel` control. And, I have several forms. I want to locate this `UserControl` in forms and dock to bottom.
The problem is that the buttons aligned to the right. I want to left. How to do this.
[image]
PS. I am using DevExpress, but it's not necessary. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here're some solutions may be the optimum but i works

1. 1- you can make each button in a separate small panel and change
   it's padding and dock these tow panels to the parent panel
2. 2- you can use separators which is much easier and set its color to
   the parent panel color( and dock them to the right too).> from right to left: button splitter button .

Answer (score 2):

There is a property called dock for every control in winforms AFAIK. Use it.
Or you can use the X and Y position values of this usercontrol to set. But upon form resizing, you have to reposition your control as well.

Comment: If I used Dock for every control, then they stick together.

Comment: I belive you can use dock for specific controls as well. So why for every 1? You just want those buttons at bottom to be alighned at right side right??

Answer (score 1):

I would put the buttons in a 1 row 2 column tablelayoutpanel where the row height=autosize, the first column's width is 100% and the 2nd column's width is autosized. I would then add the buttons to each column and set the anchor to top-right on each.

I also provided code for a Form that does this.

Form.cs:

```
using System;
```

using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication8
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView dataGridView1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel tableLayoutPanel1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button button1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button button2;

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.dataGridView1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView();
        this.tableLayoutPanel1 = new System.Windows.Forms.TableLayoutPanel();
        this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        this.button2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.dataGridView1)).BeginInit();
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.SuspendLayout();
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // dataGridView1
        // 
        this.dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumnHeadersHeightSizeMode.AutoSize;
        this.dataGridView1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;
        this.dataGridView1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
        this.dataGridView1.Name = "dataGridView1";
        this.dataGridView1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(620, 269);
        this.dataGridView1.TabIndex = 0;
        // 
        // tableLayoutPanel1
        // 
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.AutoSize = true;
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.AutoSizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoSizeMode.GrowAndShrink;
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnCount = 2;
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Percent, 100F));
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.ColumnStyle());
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.button1, 1, 0);
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(this.button2, 0, 0);
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Bottom;
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 240);
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.Name = "tableLayoutPanel1";
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount = 1;
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle());
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(620, 29);
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.TabIndex = 1;
        // 
        // button1
        // 
        this.button1.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
        this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(542, 3);
        this.button1.Name = "button1";
        this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
        this.button1.TabIndex = 0;
        this.button1.Text = "button1";
        this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        // 
        // button2
        // 
        this.button2.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
        this.button2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(461, 3);
        this.button2.Name = "button2";
        this.button2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
        this.button2.TabIndex = 1;
        this.button2.Text = "button2";
        this.button2.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        // 
        // Form1
        // 
        this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
        this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
        this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(620, 269);
        this.Controls.Add(this.tableLayoutPanel1);
        this.Controls.Add(this.dataGridView1);
        this.Name = "Form1";
        this.Text = "Form1";
        ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.dataGridView1)).EndInit();
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.ResumeLayout(false);
        this.PerformLayout();

    }
}
```

}